# Marklogic Template Driven Extraction: insert template

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to upload a template to use with MarkLogic Template Driven Extraction. I'm using Javascript in the console (on localhost). However, no matter what I try, I keep getting the same error when I try to upload. The error: "[javascript] SEC-INVALIDPERM: xdmp:document-insert...." I gave myself all the permissions that are possible, but I still keep getting the error.

```js
'use strict'

declareUpdate();
var tde = require("/MarkLogic/tde.xqy");
var MatchesTDE = xdmp.toJSON(
  {
    "template": {
      "context": "/com.marklogic.client.mapper.MatchesDoc",
      "collections": ["com.marklogic.client.mapper.MatchesDoc"],
      "rows": [
        {
          "schemaName": "mapper",
          "viewName": "matches",
          "columns": [
            {
              "name": "nrOfDocumentsInNC",
              "scalarType": "long",
              "val": "nrOfDocumentsInNC"
            },
            {
              "name": "totalNrOfDocuments",
              "scalarType": "long",
              "val": "totalNrOfDocuments"
            },
            {
              "name": "matchesID",
              "scalarType": "long",
              "val": "matchesID"
            },
            {
              "name": "uniqueInNC",
              "scalarType": "boolean",
              "val": "uniqueInNC"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
);

tde.templateInsert(
  "/MatchesDoc/TDE.json" ,
  MatchesTDE,
  xdmp.defaultPermissions(),
  ["com.marklogic.client.autorelationmapper.MatchesDoc"]
);
```

By the way, if I validate the template with `tde.validate([MatchesTDE]);` I get `true`. And if I test the script with

```js
tde.nodeDataExtract( 
  [cts.doc( "com.marklogic.client.mapper.MatchesDoc/2722286.json" )],
  [MatchesTDE]
);
```

it works. Moreover, when I follow the tutorial on TDE at https://developer.marklogic.com/learn/template-driven-extraction everything works **except** the insertTemplate function. I also get the same error there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which version of MarkLogic are we talking about?

Comment: also make sure you have the 'tde-admin' role added to the user who is executing this query.

Comment: I'm using MarkLogic 9.0. And yes, I have added the 'tde-admin' role.

Comment: Are you executing tde.templateInsert() in the context of the content database?  Does the content database have a schemas database?

Comment: I'm running it on the content database (JSON document store), it doesn't have a schema. I'm trying to use TDE to be able to use SQL. And to use it for the ODBC driver to be able to visualize the data in Tableau.

Comment: The question wasn't about a schema.  Is the content database configured through the Admin UI to have a schemas database?  It must have a schemas database even if the content is JSON.  tde.templateInsert() writes the template to the schemas database, which is where the indexer finds it.

Comment: So I've set up a schemas database and tried use tde.templateInsert in the context of the schema database. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Just to confirm:  are you calling tde.templateInsert() in the context of the content database (where the content database has been configured to have a schemas database)?  That's the desired approach.

Comment: Yes, I've tried to call it in the context of both the content DB and the schema DB. Neither works. In the schema DB settings, the default configuration for schema DB is 'none'. I tried changing that to 'schemas', no luck there either.

Comment: To be clear, td.templateInsert() will only work if executed in the context of a content database that has been configured with a schema database.  Apparently, some other issue has to be identified, but be sure to investigate with that baseline context in place.

Comment: What specific version of MarkLogic 9.0 are you using (9.0-1.1, 9.0-2, ...)?

Comment: Try `tde.templateInsert()` with only the first two arguments. The last two are optional. (it doesn't look the problem is your user's rights, rather that `xdmp.defaultPermissions` is giving you something invalid to pass into `templateInsert`)

Answer (score 1):

Try *removing* all the permissions for the user running this code. Or try running the `tde.templateInsert()` with an empty 3rd argument:

```js
tde.templateInsert(
  "/MatchesDoc/TDE.json" ,
  MatchesTDE,
  [],
  ["com.marklogic.client.autorelationmapper.MatchesDoc"]
);
```

It sounds like this is your problem:

> I gave myself all the permissions that are possible, but I still keep getting the error.

Users don't have permissions, documents have permissions. Users only have default permissions for when they write documents.

A user's default permissions are the set of permissions that get assigned to a document that the user inserts. Default permissions *do not* grant that user any additional powers in the database. Normally, an admin user has no default permissions assigned to it.

When you assign all those default permissions to your user, you end up adding a huge list of permissions in the 3rd argument of `tde.templateInsert()` where you pass `xdmp.defaultPermissions()`. At least one of those is somehow invalid, so you're getting the SEC-INVALIDPERM error.

Comment: Tried it all. Ultimately, what solved my problem was to do a complete re-install and removing all the data. Now, everything works like a charm.